# Vigenere Decryption with key length

Tags: keys, decryption, vigenere

I have a question. If I have 2 ciphertexts given and the same key has been used on both. They key lenght is the same as the plaintext and cipherrtext length. How do I decrypt them and find the key. So far I know that c1 + c2 = p1 + p2.

Comment: You might use crib-dragging, however, have you tried Kasiski's test and some online tools?

Comment: I have not heard of Kasiski'test as I am in week 5 of Computer Security module in uni but I tried almost every online tool I could find and it does not give me any results that match words from english launguage.

Comment: https://www.dcode.fr/vigenere-cipher

Comment: I used that and put in my 2 ciphertexts, then pressed decrypt with key length, which I know is 10 and not a single of the results is an actual English word.

Comment: Kasiski's test is used to determine the length of the key. Once you ask for the decrypt wiht 10, there the results are a huge list. Hint: append the the texts while striping the first one to mod 10.

Comment: I know the key length is 10. I have already gone through all hte results displayed on the page and none of are actual words. I have appended them and got the result, somewhere in the lecture said that ct1+ct2=p1+p2 (ct=ciphertext, p=plaintext) but I have no idea where to go from there.

Comment: That is crib dragging, however, you might be given a lead (hint).

Comment: 1 hour of thinking and I am still nowhere :( I dont see what hint I get from the append.